# SQL - Procedure column error

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I’m trying to create a stored procedure that does a select everything command, so I don’t have to type it out all the time. However, when I call the procure it gives me a column error.

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure LIST(in tableName varchar(35))
    BEGIN 
        SELECT * FROM tableName ;  
    END$$
```

ERROR

```
mysql> CALL LIST(Customers);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Customers' in 'field list'
```

Comment: Sounds like a great way to make for poor performance.

Comment: @NirLevy, i don’t think so, see it does list out Customers.

Comment: @Drew agreed, but now im curious  why its not working.

Comment: @John - the error you are getting is because you are passing it without quotation - the method expects to get a string and gets column name. if you'll pass `'Customers'` - it will still not work since the query inside will treat it as string and not table name. look at the link, you have an answer there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any dynamic sql must use MySQL [Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `LIST`;
DELIMITER $$
create procedure LIST(in tableName varchar(35))
BEGIN 
    SET @sql=CONCAT('select * from ',tablename);
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm1;
END$$
```

test:

```
call LIST('course');
call LIST('tutor');
```