# MySQL: Count rows of a table that is named in the current table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm new to Sql and can't seem to find an answer anywhere!...

I have a table "a" that contains a column "table_name" with the name of another table "b".

I would like to query the columns in table "a" and add an extra column with a count of the rows in table "b".

Something along these lines:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a.table_name) AS num_rows FROM a;
```

Unfortunately, I can't reference a table in the "FROM" clause like this. How can I go about this?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Just to clarify, I want **all** the rows in table "a" with an added column containing the row count of table "b": the name of table "b" is in column "table_name" in table "a".

Comment: Put the table name in a variable, then visit the [original answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809943/how-to-select-from-mysql-where-table-name-is-variable)

Comment: put tricky dynamic strings together with a `concat` noting that you can have more than 2 parameters to concat such as `concat( ... , .... , .... )` and see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40710949

Comment: @ringø I've already tried this but maybe I'm not seeing the solution. I want *all* the rows in table "a" with an added column containing the row count of table "b": the name of table "b" is in column "table_name" in table "a".